# Are Phenol and Alchohol both hydrocarbons?

Tags: hydrocarbons, phenols

In many books there are said that Alchohols are hydrocarbons, and some says they are not. On the other hand Phenols are said aromatic hydrocarbons. It is well known that Phenols are not Alchohol. Which is correct and why?

Comment: Hydrocarbons do not contain oxygen atoms.

Comment: So, how Phenol can be aromatic hydrocarbon?

Comment: Can you write a brief about that as an answer please? Please. :), I'm a school student learning organic chemistry at a primary stage.

Comment: Can you *name* the books that say such nonsense, so that others might be warned about them?

Answer (score 2):

[Phenols](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/P04539) are hydroxyderivates of aromatic hydrocarbons, with hydroxy group attached to an aromatic benzene ring, or more generally aren carbon ring.

[Alcohols](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/A00204) are hydroxyderivates of alifatic hydrocarbons, with hydroxy group attached to a saturated carbon atom.

[Hydrocarbons](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/H02889) contain hydrogen and carbon, nothing more. Phenols and alcohols contain also oxygen, so they are not hydrocarbons.